# Backup utility pops up automatically

Tags: backup

In 14.04, how to stop it from popping up automatically? Without UbuntuOne if one does not have any other cloud account, it is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Backups settings, go to Overview and check that "automatic backups" is off.

Comment: Thanks. It's just a button on top right. I set it to off position.

Comment: Terrific. It worked. Annoying pop-ups have stopped. Thanks.